# jQuery Swapping <TD> every second <TR> (nth-child)

Tags: jquery, html-table, css-selectors, swap

How to swap the TD's 'course_text' and 'course_date' on every row? I want to show a filter of five custom posts, but on every row these two have to swap.

```
<table class="course">
    <tr>
    <td class="course_text">
    <a href="<?php the_permalink(); ?>"><h3 class="course_title"><?php the_title(); ?></h3></a><br />
    <div class="course_excerpt"><?php the_excerpt(); ?></div>
    </td>
    <td class="course_date">
    <?php

    $dateformatstring_day = "l";
    $dateformatstring_month = "d";
    $dateformatstring_year = "F";
    $unixtimestamp = strtotime(get_field('cursusdatum'));

    echo '<div class="course_day">';
    echo date_i18n($dateformatstring_day, $unixtimestamp);
    echo '</div><br />';
    echo '<div class="course_month">';
    echo date_i18n($dateformatstring_month, $unixtimestamp);
    echo '</div><br />';
    echo '<div class="course_year">';
    echo date_i18n($dateformatstring_year, $unixtimestamp);
    echo '</div>';

    ?>      
    </td>
    </tr>
    </table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can try something like this -

```
$('td.course_date').each(function(){
   var $tr = $(this).closest('tr');
   $(this).prependTo($tr);
});
```

Comment: This is very nice! But, it swaps on every <TR>. How to make append it only to the second and fourth one?